# Dynamically generate a chain of promises with async/await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

Say, I need to repeat an AJAX request N times sequentially.

Normally (i. e. without async/await), I would use `reduce` to chain promises:

```js
function timeout (ms = 1000) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

function request (message, ms = 1000) {
  return timeout(ms).then(() => console.log(message))
}

function makeArray (i) {
  return new Array(i).fill(null);
}

makeArray(5).reduce(
  (promise, _, i) => promise.then(() => request(i)),
  Promise.resolve()
)
```

How do I rewrite this code with async/await?

Instead of `promise.then(() => request(i))` I want to do `await request(i)`.

All my attempts ended up running promises in parallel. I want sequentially.

Comment: for(let i=0;i<5;i++) await request(i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember `await` can only be invoked from a an `async` function.

Here I've just wrapped inside a function `run`, it could even be an IIFE..

In most cases when you start using `async / await`, you'll be calling from another `async` function anyway, so this little `run` stub wouldn't be required.

```js
function timeout (ms = 1000) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

function request (message, ms = 1000) {
  return timeout(ms).then(() => console.log(message))
}

async function run() {
  for (let trys = 0; trys < 5; trys ++) {
    await request(trys);
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: So my mistake was using methods like `forEach` and `map`.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov  Yes, unfortunately forEach / map etc are not yet `async` aware,.  Be nice in the next version of JS they implement it,.. But for now bluebird's Promise has a nice `map` function, and it comes with a nice option `concurrency`..

Comment: And I guess a custom async-aware `forEach` equivalent would use your answer under the hood?